# VS Code DocumentSelector for all documents?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a completion extension for VS Code. `registerCompletionItemProvider()` requires a DocumentSelector selector to specify which documents it works with. I currently have this, which seems to work, but isn't very elegant:

```
let provider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(
    [{ pattern: '**', scheme: 'file' }, { pattern: '**', scheme: 'untitled' }],
    { /* other stuff */ }
);
```

If I leave `scheme` off it works as well, but VS Code gives me a guilt-trip warning implying I should keep it. Is there a simpler way to select all documents?

Comment: Related docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/document-selector